# Get the first row for every unique value

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have an array in the following format in which each unique "Vendor" is already ordered by (using a sql query) the variable "Total_Weight" in descending order.

```
 [ { Vendor: 'AAA', id: 'FOR', Total_Weight: 61156 },
   { Vendor: 'AAA', id: 'LOC', Total_Weight: 32322 },
   { Vendor: 'BBB', id: 'LOC1', Total_Weight: 3145},
   { Vendor: 'BBB', id: 'LOC2', Total_Weight: 11}  ]
```

I need to loop over the above list and for every unique Vendor, I just need to take the first row that has the maximum Total_Weight and put "Vendor" and "id" to a new list.

Hence the result has to be

```
 [ { Vendor: 'AAA', id: 'FOR'},{Vendor: 'BBB', id: 'LOC1'}}
```

I am new to apps script programming, any leads/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `reduce` here to retrieve a list with only the first element per vendor:

```js
const data = [{ Vendor: 'AAA', id: 'FOR', Total_Weight: 61156 },
{ Vendor: 'AAA', id: 'LOC', Total_Weight: 32322 },
{ Vendor: 'BBB', id: 'LOC1', Total_Weight: 3145 },
{ Vendor: 'BBB', id: 'LOC2', Total_Weight: 11 }];

const result = data.reduce((allEntries, currentEntry) => allEntries.some(entry => entry.Vendor === currentEntry.Vendor) // if there already is an entry for the given vendor...
   ? allEntries // don't add the current entry to the list
   : [...allEntries, currentEntry], // otherwise, as the current entry is the first one for the given vendor, add it
   [] // starting value of "allEntries"
);
console.log(result);
```